# Create a tf-idf matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, tf-idf

I'm trying to read some text files and store the term frequency in a matrix where each row should be every document and thus each column in each row is the weights for every term. Then each column in the matrix should correspond to a specific term when the matrix is completed. I've managed so far to do this, however my issue is that this only works when the dimensions of the documents are the same, i.e. the same amount of words in each document.

Code as follows:

```
F = dir('*.txt');
s = [];
allWords = [];
for ii = 1:length(F) 
        filetext = fileread(F(ii).name);
        filetext = split(filetext);
        filetext = filetext';
        filetext = sort(filetext);
        allWords = [allWords, filetext];
        A = unique(allWords);
        l = length(A);
        s = [s; filetext];
end
%A = unique(allWords);
%Each row in D is one document
D = s;
out=zeros(size(D));
for k=1:numel(A)
  idx=ismember(D,A(k));
  out(:,k)=sum(idx,2);
end
disp(out)
%Matrix is as follows
%The terms are sorted as well
%0     0     1     1     1     1     1
%1     1     0     1     1     1     0
%Where I have the files example.txt and example2.txt with the contents
%we see the shining sun
%the sun is shining bright
```

What can I do to expand the matrix while still retaining the "term structure" when documents have different dimensions which of course is the real world scenario.

I do not have access to the text analytics toolbox which has a built in function for doing this.

Comment: Your `A` and `s` are exactly the same, you store `filetext` and append the next file. I guess for `s` you somehow want only the unique words or something.

Comment: That's right. I'd like to keep track of the full list of words and the unique ones as well.

Comment: So edit your code to make `s` and `allWords` different, by making `s` keep track of the unique words instead of all of them. Basically make `s=[s;A]` and you're set. (Sorry, I messed up my first comment, it were supposed to be `s` and `allWords`)